# Li-ion battery voltage monitoring

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, lithium-ion

**tl;dr How to pick resistor (or component) values to alter the triggering voltage level for the second circuit?**

Hello everyone. I have First Person View (FPV) goggles whose battery I lost. But since I have a spare 3S battery I was intending on using a buck converter to step it down to 5 V to power the goggles. The issue with this approach is that I can't read off the voltage on my goggles screen since the converter will always keep a constant output.

To solve this, I was betting on building a typical power supply (attached below) and have the output driving an astable 555 timer RESET pin and beep a buzzer when I get to a critical voltage.
[image: 5V power supply monitor with two opamps]

A few scrolls down the LT1017 datasheet, I came across the power monitor circuit below. It occurred to me that this design eliminates the need for a 555 since it has a pulsed output; I can just connect a buzzer instead of flashing an LED.[image: A power supply monitor with opamps]

The only issue with the second design is that I don't understand how the to pick the resistors to change the triggering voltage. May someone help with the approach/formulae?

Comment: Why not simulate the circuit and play around with a few values to see what threshold range the circuit can accommodate?

Comment: @Andyaka I just had to make sure that I am procedural and not just trying to hack the circuit until I get something that works.

Comment: That's fair enough if you don't understand the circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach won't work because the voltage of a Li-ion battery is a poor indicator of its state of charge (SoC). The voltage of a Li-ion battery changes more due to the current than it does due to the SoC. Also, it's the voltage of the lowest capacity cell that determines when the battery shuts down, not the voltage of the entire battery. Therefore, the battery is likely to shut down before the total battery voltage is low enough to trigger your circuit.

Therefore, even if you solve your proximate problem (your low-voltage detector circuit), it will not solve your ultimate problem (knowing when the Li-ion battery is about to run our of "juice").

---

Regardless, to answer your question:

> how to pick the resistors to change the triggering voltage

Increase the value of the 390 k resistor.

R = 120 k * Vin / 1.2 V - 120 k

Comment: I just corrected the post - it's a a lipo and not a li-ion. My take-away from your answer is that I should instead measure each of the cells in the pack. [This article](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/multi-cell-voltage-monitoring-for-lithium-battery-pack-in-electric-vehicles) shows a way of multi-cell measuring.

I can then check if any of the cells has run out of juice ~3.2V.

Comment: @Montso  What you call "LiPo" **IS** a Li-ion cell. It's packaged in a pouch, but it **IS** a Li-ion cell nonetheless. Chemically and electrically there is no difference. Only the package varies. Please see this table: https://imgur.com/a/PPNeI

Comment: it makes sense. Let me stay on the problem. I think I have so far figured the measuring individual cells issue.

Comment: it makes sense. Let me stay on the problem. I think I have so far figured the measuring individual cells issue.

Does it make sense to actively balance the cells and then measure just one cell, counting on the cells having the same voltage?

Comment: "Does it make sense to actively balance the cells and then measure just one cell, counting on the cells having the same voltage?" Absolutely not. Cell voltages do not divide equally. See: http://liionbms.com/php/wp_lovtg_cutoff.php

Comment: I realise that the only way to go about it is a BMS - up till now, I have been trying to cut corners. Now, I do have a good LiPo charger (EV Peak A1), so my main application would be building a BMS dedicating to solely monitoring the discharge. Do correct me if I'm wrong.